# Socket.io multiroom: get error socket.in is not a function

Tags: socket.io

Try to make multiroom with socket.io. On the client side (Jade):

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var socket = io();

    function test(){
        socket.emit('join', '#{user._id}');
        socket.in('#{user._id}').emit('chat message', 'test sent');

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
    }
```

On the server side:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });

    socket.on('join', function (_id) {
        socket.join(_id);
        console.log('Joined room: ' + _id);
    });

    socket.on('loc', function (position) {
        console.log('pos: ' + position);
    });
});
```

And when the script runs in a browser, it causes 'socket.in is not a function'.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear for me from the socket.io docs, but, shortly:
**Client send only with `socket.emit('new message', 'to room name', 'I am new message')`. All the routing between rooms is made on server as follows: `io.on('new message', function(room, data) { io.sockets.in(room).emit('new msg to client', data)...`**

Thanx to article [here](http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/)